# Restore files from software RAID 1

Tags: docker, software-raid

I accidentally erased my files from my MDADM raid when I created a Docker container and mapped my raid but after that all files in the raid disappeared. The discs are not currently being written or read. I want to ask what is the way I can recover my files? Unfortunately I don't have a backup. Also I am open to any suggestions even to attach disks to Windows machine. This is my Docker compose config file which I used --> https://pastebin.com/PqwEkZ4G

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by "mapping my raid"? What exactly you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAID layer simply replicated the removal operation to each RAID member, so correctly operating RAID can't possibly help in this situation. This is precisely why RAID is not a replacement for a backup.

Therefore, if RAID was operating correctly, the recovery procedure is absolutely the same as that for a single drive. It always begins with the disk dump to have "unlimited retries".

The rest depends on the structure you had inside the array — partitioning, LVM, filesystems, etc.. Scan for removed files, recreated filesystems, etc., all that painful stuff. Without the detailed information about the structure and often data it has there is no way to suggest anything more concrete. And even after that, chances are not very high.